# Kubernetes Java API for Metrics

Tags: java, kubernetes

I am getting the pod metrics through kubectl command

```
➜  kubectl top pods
NAME                CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
api-6bd876fc8b-85dnx   72m          553Mi
ui-67b794cf8d-gcrg5    0m           1Mi
```

but I want to try through Java client https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/

Is there any support to get the Metrics for Pods and Nodes through kubernetes-client ?

Answer (score 2):

The Resource Metrics API is not included in the official Java client library.
so you have to query the API server as following:

```
GET /apis/metrics/v1alpha1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods/{pod}
```

which will return the results of current metrics.

Here are a few references with ability to add even more custom metrics:

- https://blog.jetstack.io/blog/resource-and-custom-metrics-hpa-v2/
- https://github.com/kubernetes/metrics

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

as blue man said, it is now possible to get this metrics
Java Solution

```java
PodMetricsList list = new Metrics(client).getPodMetrics("playground");

for(PodMetrics podMetrics:list.getItems()){
    for(ContainerMetrics containerMetrics:podMetrics.getContainers()){
                System.out.println(containerMetrics.getUsage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Solution

```
val client = Config.defaultClient();
Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);
Metrics(client).getPodMetrics(
        "name-space"
).items.forEach {
    it.containers.forEach {metrics ->
        println(metrics.usage)
    }
}
```

This should give the metrics you are looking for.

Sample Output

```
{cpu=Quantity{number=0.011135729, format=DECIMAL_SI}, memory=Quantity{number=831680512, format=BINARY_SI}}

{cpu=Quantity{number=0.008742460, format=DECIMAL_SI}, memory=Quantity{number=781041664, format=BINARY_SI}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can test with your Kubernetes cluster by changing the following parameters.(should be installed metrics server on your cluster)

`ApiClient client;` //create client as you wish

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.Configuration;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.Pair;
import io.kubernetes.client.util.Config;
import okhttp3.Call;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

String apiPath = "    ";
        Object localVarPostBody = null;
        List<Pair> localVarCollectionQueryParams = new ArrayList <>();
        List < Pair > localVarQueryParams = new ArrayList <>();
        localVarQueryParams.addAll(client.parameterToPair("pretty", "true"));
        Map <String, String> localVarHeaderParams = new HashMap <>();
        Map<String, String> localVarCookieParams = new HashMap <>();
        Map<String, Object> localVarFormParams = new HashMap <>();
        String[] localVarAccepts = new String[]{"application/json"};
        String localVarAccept = client.selectHeaderAccept(localVarAccepts);
        if (localVarAccept != null) {
            localVarHeaderParams.put("Accept", localVarAccept);
        }
        String[] localVarContentTypes = new String[0];
        String localVarContentType = client.selectHeaderContentType(localVarContentTypes);
        localVarHeaderParams.put("Content-Type", localVarContentType);
        String[] localVarAuthNames = new String[]{"BearerToken"};
        Call call = client.buildCall(apiPath, "GET", localVarQueryParams, localVarCollectionQueryParams, localVarPostBody, localVarHeaderParams, localVarCookieParams, localVarFormParams, localVarAuthNames, null);
        JsonElement element = (JsonElement)client.execute(call, JsonElement.class).getData();
        System.out.println(element);
```

apiPath = /apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods/{pod} ,
/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/pods

you can get usage of "cpu" and "memory" according to the **container vice** under the **pod name**.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.kubernetes</groupId>
    <artifactId>client-java</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```