# Get resource usage on k8s pod in java API

Tags: kubernetes, containers, resources

I am trying to get resource usage for a container using Kubernetes API in Java (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/).
Could someone please guide on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean Resource Requests/Limits, not usage?

Comment: Hi @Daigo , I am looking for resource usage not limit. Limit I could get from container specification.

Comment: Then does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61825748/kubernetes-java-api-for-metrics